# LIghtbox2 hide header and footer regions

Tags: javascript

I had created a lightbox which contains the node title and body content. But it shows the Admin bar of drupal , Header and Footer regions. I want to remove these from the lightbox and showing only the content of node on lightbox.

I am using Lightbox2 module for  this.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering directly but proposing an alternative solution here:

If possible, switch to [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox), extend it with [Colorbox Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) and use it to easily display your nodes without header and footer like this:

```
<a class="colorbox-node" href="blogs/my-example?width=600&height=600">My Example</a>
```